# Regex for XML Schema

Tags: regex, xml, nsregularexpression

I just need help with a regular expression of a back camera of a mobile phone to put in my XML Schema but just can't seem to get it right. The issue is that some mobile phones have 4 cameras and some just two and I can't come up with a way to capture the whole group in one match and the changes that occur when having more cameras.

**These are the strings I'm working with:**

- 50 Mpx (f/1,88) + 13 Mpx (f/2,4) + 5 Mpx (f/2,4)
- 12 Mpx (f/1,6) + 12 Mpx (f/2,4)
- 64 Mpx (f/1,8) + 8 Mpx (f/2,3) + 2 Mpx (f/2,4) + 2 Mpx (f/2,4)

**And this is the regex I came up with but doesn't match.**

```
(\d+\sMpx\s\(f\/\d\,\d+\))(\s\+\s)*
```

Would you be able to transform my expression so it captures the strings above?

Thank you so much!

Comment: This is one whole match `\d+\sMpx\s\(f\/\d,\d+\)(?:\s\+\s\d+\sMpx\s\(f\/\d,\d+\))*` https://regex101.com/r/Orbc35/1

Answer (score 0):

The pattern that you tried has 2 capture groups, which you do not need for a match only. As the pattern with `Mpx` is not repeated, you get separate matches.

The part `(\s\+\s)*` at the end is optional, and will also match trailing  `+`

To get a single match, you can first match the first part with Mpx and then optionally repeat the  `+`  part followed by matching again the first part.
In the repetition you can use a non capture group `(?:` instead.

**Note** that you don't have to escape the comma, and depending on the regex delimiters you also don't have to escape the forward slash.

```
\d+\sMpx\s\(f\/\d,\d+\)(?:\s\+\s\d+\sMpx\s\(f\/\d,\d+\))*
```

**Explanation**

- `\d+\sMpx\s\(f\/\d,\d+\)` Match 1+ digits, whitespace char, `(f/`, single digit, comma and 1+ digits
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\s\+\s` Match `+` between whitespace chars
  - `\d+\sMpx\s\(f\/\d,\d+\)` Match the Mpx pattern again
- `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat it

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Orbc35/1).